# Issues with Hello World project for SharePoint 2019

Tags: spfx, 2019

I have the following versions on my machine:

```
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.4.1
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- typescript@2.4.0
`-- yo@3.1.1
```

Scaffolding in Yeoman, I have selected the option SharePoint 2016 onwards. When I run gulp serve I get the following:

> ```
>  Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
> at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dchiev\node_modules\tslint\lib\linter.js:20:10)
> at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } [11:21:06] Error - Unknown  Cannot find module
> ```
>
> 'typescript' [11:21:07] ==================[ Finished
> ]================== [11:21:07] Project helloworld version: 0.0.1
> [11:21:07] Build tools version: 2.5.3 [11:21:07] Node version: v8.9.0
> [11:21:07] Total duration: 3.97 s [11:21:07] Task errors: 2

Any help would be great!

Comment: what version of node are you using? `node -v`. Can you asl run `npm list --depth=0 -g` and update your post to include this info? This might be helpful too: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

Comment: for node: v8.9.0
npm: 5.5.1 
sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some SPFx for SP 2016, and what I have that works is:

```
Node v8.17.0
```

then the only things I have installed *globally* are:

```
@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.1  // previously had listed 1.13.0 but that actually doesn't work for 2016/Node 8.17, must be 1.12.1
gulp-cli@1.2.2
npm@6.13.4
yo@3.1.1
```

Then after scaffolding out the project, the generator added `gulp@3.9.1` as a dev dependency.  I don't see `typescript` referenced anywhere, but I do see it in my `node_modules`.

Oh, and I definitely do *not* use the `--skip-install` flag when running `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`, I let it do it's thing and manage the full install of everything it needs.

---

To address Denis Molodtsov's comment:

I hear what you are saying but I am telling you for a fact that the versions I listed above do work to create a SPFx web part for SP 2016 (I've made a few so far).

I spent the better part of a day testing different combinations of different versions of the tools to see what works, and that's what I ended up with.

I can't speak on SP 2019 / SPFx v.1.4.1 because I haven't needed to make any web parts for 2019 yet so I haven't gone through the drill of figuring out the right combination of the highest versions of things that work, but I would think that if this version combination works for 2016, it would also probably work for 2019.

Yes it's true that the version of *SPFx* that is supported on 2016 is v1.1, but you can use <strike>the most recent</strike> v1.12.1 (or possibly earlier versions) of the *generator* to scaffold out the project, as long as you are selecting the option to create a web part for 2016.  I can see in my `package.json` that the SPFx packages scaffolded (`sp-core-library`, `sp-webpart-base`, etc) are indeed version 1.1.

As far as the compatibility matrix you linked to, I know that that says that you should use Node v.6 for SPFx v1.1, but because of the issue [discussed here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support#impact-of-nodejs-v6-nodejs-v8-http1--http2):

> Around this the time of the v1.1 release, Node.js was transitioning
> from Node.js v6.x to v8.x. In this update, Node.js introduced a change
> where the default HTTP protocol switched from HTTP1 to HTTP2. SPFx
> v1.1 was written for HTTP1, not HTTP2, so this change affected the
> local web server for SPFx v1.1 projects.
>
> In Node.js v8.x, you can force HTTP1 by setting the following
> environment variable to instruct Node.js to use HTTP1 instead of the
> default HTTP2: NODE_NO_HTTP2=1. This environment variable only exists
> in Node.js v8.x. That's why if you're building SPFx solutions for
> SharePoint Server 2016, you should use Node.js v8.x.

So even though the compatibility matrix says use Node v.6, you actually *have to* use Node v.8 so you're able to set that environment variable.

I even change my npm script in `package.json` to be:

```
"dev": "set NODE_NO_HTTP2=1&& gulp serve"
```

As an additional aside, I have found that you can't use `yarn` as your package manager for this setup because `yarn` does some additional version/compatibility checking which will prevent you from adding other dependencies into your project, so you have to stick with `npm` only.

Comment: Hi @Dylan. I think, SPFx is very particular about versions of node, npm, etc. For example, SP 2016 only supports SPFx 1.1 generator. Versions of node and npm are also supposed to be lower: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov, updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: wow, great research. Thank you. I didn't know I can use a new generator for SP2016/2019. I also remember the HTTP-related issue a few years ago. looks like the official compatibility  matrix needs more updates.